# Java: Are built-in implementations of data structures inefficient?

Tags: java, data-structures

One big reason I like to use Java (as compared to say, C) is that there are lots of built in data structures available (like the Collections API). However, are the implementations of these data structures sub-optimal? For better performance, will I be better off writing my own implementations?

Comment: C++ has the exact same structures as Java IIRC.

Comment: What performance characteristics do you need?  If they meet them then writing your own will not be beneficial.  If they do not, then perhaps writing your own or profiling your code to check for performance bottle-necks would be the prudent next step.

Comment: Depends on which structures and which definitions of efficient.  Efficient with CPU, memory, disk, multi-core, distributed computing, bandwidth...?  Small data sets, large data sets...?  The core Java libraries are pretty huge.  Java is now quite mature, so the core data structures are unlikely to change much.  Future versions will extend functionality, but probably not affect existing performance much.

Comment: @Will Actually I believe performance will increase (at least I hope). The interfaces themselves should not change very much. The interfaces are pretty solid so I doubt they will end up changing a lot.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos first comment: I did not know that. Thanks for informing. Anyway, my question is still regarding built in implementation vs custom implementation. Edited the question.

Comment: If you need specialized implementations of containers, check out Trove for primitive collections, Javolution for deterministic realtime collections, and Guava for more robust hashes.  They all solve different use cases, so choose what's appropriate, not just what benchmarks fast.

Answer (score 8):

I would not waste any time re-implementing any of the classes in Java's Collections library until I had a concrete performance problem to solve.  The built-in classes have been tested by thousands of people.  They're proven to work, and they're performant for most general use cases.  I've found that most of the time when I find a performance issue with a Collection class, it's because someone chose the wrong data structure for the problem, not the wrong implementation of that data structure.

Comment: Tested by millions of people really.

Comment: @EJP Most likely.  I didn't want to overstate my case.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The built-in implementations are very fast (they've been built with performance in mind) and are fast enough for the vast majority of applications.

Whether it's fast enough for your case will depend on your application and your hardware, for example if you have a fast CPU, but memory is constrained or vice versa can make a huge difference.

If you're developing something that *needs* to be extremely performant, I'd suggest starting by creating a little test project with the kind of data load and processing level you need to support to give yourself extra confidence that it will be fast enough running on your target hardware. If it's not, you may be able to tweak the algorithms, buy better hardware, use caching etc. or switch to a language that is "closer to the metal".

Be careful not to fall into the trap of optimizing everything - usually it's only a very small part of the application that needs to be optimized.

Answer (score -2):

The greatest strength of the JCF is the flexibility not necessarily the performance; it has a great design that permits you to easily change from one collection to another. It has utility classes for making them thread safe, immutable etc. or you can implement your own custom collections (by implementing the interface and compose it with the nearest existing implementation):

```
public MyList<E> implements List<E> {
    private List<E> holdingList = new ArrayList<E>();

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        //your custom needs
    }
    //delegate non custom ones to holdingList    
}
```

If you are really pressed by performance issues then you probably should use good old arrays, but in the majority of the cases this is not necessarily.

However you should know a little about the internals of JCF in order to obtain the best performance out of them; from a point of view they can be criticized because they tend to consume large amounts of memory.

Some basic things: it's good to know that the sorting used is merge sort which sorts in-place sorting but is a little slower than quick sort. You should predict the size of the collection you are going to use and pass it as a value to the constructor and not always rely on the default value. Another important thing is to choose the proper collection; don't use a Map when a List would do because it takes way more memory. You should also make sure that you don't keep useless empty collections around, because they too take memory. You can find a great article about collections and memory usage [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-codetoheap/index.html).

Comment: The obvious way to implement MyList is to *extend* ArrayList, not have to write dozens of delegation methods. Arrays.sort() uses Quicksort if I remember correctly. You wouldn't use a Map where you needed a List *because it's the wrong collection:* it's not just a memory-based decision.

Comment: @EJP The obvious but bad-OOP-design-way to implement MyList is to extend ArrayList; the proper way is by composition as shown above - see Item 16 in Effective Java, book written by the author of JCF. The sorting algorithm is an optimized merge sort - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/index.html . I am pretty sure there are others that have written a Map<Integer, ValueType> which can be replaced by a List<ValueType> in most cases.; it is obvious that you do not choose from Map or List by memory decision but you should consider it if you really want performance.